# WebBrowser Control programming Tabs within Document pages query

Tags: asp.net, browser, controls

I am trying to download information from a website and I have hit (yet another) brick wall in a long and tiresome journey to get something productive developed.

I have a program which uses *WebBrowser* to login to a site - with a valid username and password - therby allowing me to set up a legitimate connection to it and retrieve information (my own) from it.

From the initial page presented to me after login, I can use `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")` and `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Some Id")` etc. to work my way around the website, and processing all the *DocumentCompleted* events returned until ...  I arrive at a page which appears to have a *TabControl* embedded in it.

I need to be able to choose the middle Tab of this control, and retrieve the information it holds.  When I access this information 'normally' (i.e. from IE and not from my *WebBrowser* program) I can click each of the three tabs and information duly appears - so its there, tantalisingly so ... but can I manupulate these Tabs from my program?  I feel it should be possible, but I can't see how I can do it.

The problem manifests itself because when I am processing the page which has the Tab in it my code looks like this:

```
static void wb_TabPage(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    HtmlElement element;

    element = wb.Document.GetElementById("Bills");  // Find the "Bills" tab
    element.InvokeMember("Click");                  // Click the "Bills" tab

    // Unhook THIS routine from DocumentCompleted delivery
    wb.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_TabPage);
    // Hook up this routine - for the next 'Document Completed' delivery - which never arrives!
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_Bills);

    return;
}
```

And that's the problem - no more Documents are ever 'Completed' for me to process, even after the InvokeMember("Click").  It seems for all the world that the Tabs are being updated inplace, and no amount of Refresh(ing) or Navigating or Event Handling will allow me to get to a place or in a position where I can get the data from them

Does anybody have any idea how I can do this? Does anybody know how to manipulate Tabs from WebBrowser? Thanks in advance if you do ...

Comment: In normal use, does clicking a tab reload the page? if not is the data loaded in the background when a tab is clicked or is it there when the page loads initially?

Comment: Yes, when I access the website from - say IE - and I locate the page and click the tabs, the data changes (each tab displays different data btw).  I've looked at the HTML source when each tab is clicked, and they're all different, so the data IS being refreshed in the background on each Tab click, its not all there when the page is initially loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try using the findcontrol function on your page.  You will likely need to drill into the tab control itself to find the tab page and the controls contained in it.